# Replacing one character in a string with multiple characters in C

Tags: c, string, replace

If I have a string as follows:
"Dragonballs are cool."

but I want to change the spaces into multiple lines: "---"

So this would be the end result: Dragonballs---are---cool.

How would i do it? Is a loop necessary (I know how to replace single characters with another single character), or is there another way to it?

Comment: An array is not the right data structure here, just saying.

Comment: Even if there was a standard function which could do it, it would need to use loops. You can't get away from that fact. And no, there's no standard function which can do it for you, you have to do it yourself (for example by copying characters to a new array, and add multiple characters in the new array when you find the character you want to replace).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no problem, it's gone now. :)

Comment: Since your new string will be bigger than the original one you'll need a bigger memory buffer (or your initial buffer should be big enough to fit the new string).

Comment: find first space in the string (`strpbrk` or `strchr` or loop), shift the right part from the space of the string 2 characters to the right (just `memmove`) (`realloc` the array of needed), input the `---`, repeat.

Comment: You could think of this task in terms of encapsulating into a function, perhaps `char *search_replace(const char *orig_str, const char *to_replace, const char *replace_with);`.

Comment: How about paired characters?  Should change 'o' to  "---" make "Drag---nballs are c---l." or "Drag---nballs are c------l."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways it can be done. One way is to tokenize the string first, to find out where the spaces are, for example by using `strtok`.

Then copy the different sub strings (words) one by one into a new string (character array), for example with `strcat`. For each string you copy, also copy a string `"---"`.

The alternative is to just do all this manually without calling any string library functions.

Yes, you will need loops.

Answer (score 1):

I made an example program you can examine if you like. The biggest problem you'll encounter when replacing sub-strings is that you may need more room than the original source string has. So normally you want to write the modified source string somewhere else. You can use useful functions like `strncat` and `strncmp` to work around situations where you have a destination buffer that could be smaller than the expanded source.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUF_LEN         32
#define MIN(p,q)            ((p) < (q) ? (p) : (q))


void replace (const char *src, char *buf, size_t buf_size, const char *pat, const char *rep) {
    size_t pat_len = strlen(pat), rep_len = strlen(rep);
    int inc, i = 0;
    const char *p = NULL;

    while (*src != '\0') {

        // Here, if we detect a match, we set our copy pointer and increment size.
        if (strncmp(src, pat, pat_len) == 0) {
            inc = MIN(buf_size - i - 1, rep_len);
            p = rep;
        } else {
            inc = MIN(buf_size - i - 1, 1);
            p = src;
        }

        // If we ran out of room in the buffer, we break out of the loop here.
        if (inc <= 0) break;

        // Here we append the chosen buffer with the increment size. Then increment our indexes.
        buf = strncat(buf, p, inc);
        i += inc;
        ++src;
    }

    // Don't forget the null-character.
    buf[i] = '\0';
}

int main (void) {
    const char *src = "Hello World!";
    const char *match = " ";
    const char *repl = "...";
    char buf[MAX_BUF_LEN] = {0};

    replace(src, buf, MAX_BUF_LEN, match, repl);

    fprintf(stdout, "The string \"%s\" has been transformed to \"%s\"\n", src, buf);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```